# AS3 How to find current location of mc?

Tags: actionscript-3

**Thanks for the startdrag() suggestions, but I'm trying to avoid that atm**

I'm trying to create a drag motion by using mouse_down then the mc = mouseX. Here is [an image of the situation](http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/8584/grabpoint.jpg)

But when I click, the mc always jumps to its registration point, which is the top left corner atm.

I can't work my head around how to grab the current location of the mc. **Note that the mc (all_mc) is wider than the stage.**

Can someone please help me out?

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);

function mouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent) {
    this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
}

function mouseMoveHandler(e:MouseEvent) {
    all_mc.x = mouseX;
}
```

Edit:

Ok I kind of worked out the x location of the mouse in relation to the registration point of the mc (the registration is at the top left):

```
Math.abs(stage.x - all_mc.x) + mouseX
```

But how to I select that point of on the mc?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted some code you're working on. Probably what you're looking for though is to calculate a difference between where the MC is located and the position of the mouse. Something like this: var dx:Number = <your_mc>.x - <mouse_position>.x. When you release the mouse just add that value(dx), to the position of where the mouse was when the button was released.

Comment: I've added the code. My problem is the mc is bigger than the stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified Marty Wallace's answer to handle the difference between where you click and the registration point:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class DummyTest extends Sprite {

        private var mDeltaX:Number = 0;
        private var mDeltaY:Number = 0;

        private var mGfx:Sprite;

        public function DummyTest() {
            mGfx = new Sprite();

            with(mGfx.graphics) {
                beginFill(0x00FF00);
                drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
                endFill();
            }

            addChild(mGfx);

            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
        }

        private function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent) : void {
            mDeltaX = mGfx.x - mouseX;
            mDeltaY = mGfx.y - mouseY;

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);
        }

        private function onMouseUp(e:MouseEvent) : void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
            removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);
        }

        private function onEnterFrame(e:Event) : void {
            mGfx.x = parent.mouseX + mDeltaX;
            mGfx.y = parent.mouseY + mDeltaY;
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;

var mc:MovieClip;
var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite  ;
sprite.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
sprite.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
sprite.graphics.endFill();

this.addChild(sprite);

sprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,function(){
    sprite.startDrag();}
);
sprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,function(){
    sprite.stopDrag();}
);
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to avoid using startdrag atm

Answer (score 0):

[startDrag()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Sprite.html#startDrag%28%29) has a `lockCenter` argument which you could try playing with.

> **`lockCenter:Boolean`** (default =
>   `false`) — Specifies whether the
>   draggable sprite is locked to the
>   center of the mouse position (`true`),
>   or locked to the point where the user
>   first clicked the sprite (`false`).

---

### Without startDrag as per comment

---

Make this the base class of an object that you want to drag:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Draggable extends Sprite
    {
        // vars
        private var _hx:Number = 0;
        private var _hy:Number = 0;

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function Draggable()
        {
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, _mouseDown);
        }

        /**
         * MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN
         */
        private function _mouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            _hx = mouseX;
            _hy = mouseY;

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _handle);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _mouseUp);
        }

        /**
         * MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP
         */
        private function _mouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _handle);
            removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _mouseUp);
        }

        /**
         * Event.ENTER_FRAME
         */
        private function _handle(e:Event):void
        {
            x = parent.mouseX - _hx;
            y = parent.mouseY - _hy;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to avoid using startdrag atm

Comment: Try that out. Sorry, took me a few minutes to write that one up.

Comment: Thanks Marty, but for some reason nothing is happening atm. When you were typing that up, I kind of worked out that **Math.abs(stage.x - all_mc.x) + mouseX** equals the current location of the mc. But I'm not sure how to select that area. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);

var positionX:Number = 0;
var positionY:Number = 0;
function mouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent) {
    positionX = all_mc.mouseX;// save the x position for future reference
    positionY = all_mc.mouseY;// save the y position for future reference

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
}

function mouseMoveHandler(e:MouseEvent) {
    all_mc.x = stage.mouseX - positionX ;
    all_mc.y = stage.mouseY - positionY ;
}

function mouseUpHandler(e:MouseEvent) {
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
}
```